# Idle Session Timeout for MFP V8.0 App

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am migrating my app from MFP V7.1 to MFP V8.0. Earlier there used to be worklight.properties file in which we can modify the session timeout value. What is the idle session timeout for MFP V8.0 app and from where it can be configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 there are no sessions... since you're based on the OAuth protocol. What you have is tokens. Tokens have expiration values... your connection to the server is invalidated once the token expiration has been reached. Read more about access tokens and token expiration in the Knowledge Center: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_oauth_security_tokens.html